# How to make pagination from an API with AJAX with the same query?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, express

I don't know how good I could the write the title but it's a little bit complicated.

So I have this webpage in `/music-maker` endpoint which have a modal. In the modal there is an input field which takes in a user input and post it to the backend through AJAX post request. Then that user query is used to make an API request to `https://example.com/api/?key=${key}&q=${query}`. The result is then displayed in the webpage.

Now that part is working as it should be but the issue comes when I try to implement an infinite scrolling feature to it.

Please note at this point that the api request above returns the first page of data only and if I specify `page 2` then it will return the data from page 2 of that exact `query`.

So whenever the user scrolls to the bottom I need to make another api request with that exact query as before but for page 2 which I am unable to accomplish. I've tried making a get AJAX request and used a global `query` variable to store the query from post request but it returns undefined.

Here are the endpoints of the app:

```
let query;

router.get('/music-maker', (req, res) => {
    res.render('music-maker');
});


router.post('/music-maker', async (req, res) => {
    query           = encodeURI(req.body.input);

    const key = '205XxXxX54825-0ab1';

    try{
        const url       = `https://example.com/api/?key=${key}&q=${query}`;
        const fullRes   = await axios.get(url);

        if( fullRes.status === 200 ) {

            return res.json({ 
                data: fullRes.data
            });
        
        }

    }catch(err) {
        res.json({
            error: 'Unable to retrieve data.'
        });
    }

});


router.get('/music-maker/page', async (req, res) => {
    console.log('1: ', query); // returns undefined
    const pageQuery         = req.query.q;

    try{
        console.log('2: ', pageQuery)
    }catch(err) {
        console.log(err)
    }

});
```

Here are the AJAX requests:

```
const formInput         = $(".searchbar input");
const userSearchInput   = formInput.val();
const modalForm         = $("form");
    
$(modalForm).submit((e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      const actionUrl = $(e.target).attr("action");
        
      $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: actionUrl,
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                input: userSearchInput
            },
            beforeSend: function() {
                $(formInput).val("");
            },
            success: function({ data }) {
                if ( data ) {
                    $(".data-container").html(data);
                } else if (data.error) {
                    $(".error-container").html(data.error);
                }
            },
            complete: function() {
                $(".loader-container").addClass("hidden");
            },
      });
});

// When the user scrolls to the bottom of the container, this ajax request fires

$('.data-container').on('scroll', function(e) {
        const elem = $(e.currentTarget);
        if (elem[0].scrollHeight - elem.scrollTop() == elem.outerHeight()) {

            console.log(userSearchInput); // this is undefined

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: `/music-maker/page/`,
                dataType: "json",
                beforeSend: function() {
                    console.log('sending');
                },
                success: function( data ) {
                    console.log('incoming');
                },
                complete: function() {
                    console.log('complete');
                },
            });

       }
});
```

How can I get the other pages' data of the same query by making an API request through AJAX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update:

server part code

```
router.get("/music-maker/search/:query/:page", async (req, res) => {
  let query = req.params.query;
  let page = req.params.page;
  console.log("query: " + query);
  console.log("page: " + page);
  
  return res.json({
    query: req.params.query,
    page: req.params.page
  });
});
```

client/browser

```
let userSearchInput = "";
let pageNumber = 1;

function getMusicMaker() {
  userSearchInput = $(".searchbar input").val();
  userSearchInput = encodeURIComponent(userSearchInput);
  const actionUrl = "/music-maker/search";
  
  $.ajax({
    url: `${actionUrl}/${userSearchInput}/${pageNumber}`,
    dataType: "json",
    beforeSend: function () {
      $(".searchbar input").val("");
    },
    success: function (data) {
      alert(data.query + "\n" + data.page)
    }
  });
}
$("form").submit((e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  pageNumber = 1; // new search, reset page number
  getMusicMaker();
});


$(".data-container").on("scroll", function (e) {
  const elem = $(e.currentTarget);
  if (elem[0].scrollHeight - elem.scrollTop() == elem.outerHeight()) {
    pageNumber++; // set page 2,3,4,....
    getMusicMaker();
  }
});
```

---

I think you have multiple problems, to fix it need whole rewrite to your code (client and server) but I suggest to use single http method, POST or GET.

endpoint for static pages list:

```
/music-maker/1
/music-maker/2
or
/music-maker = /music-maker/page/1
/music-maker/page/2
```

for search

```
/music-maker/search/keywords
/music-maker/search/keywords/2
/music-maker/search/keywords/3
```

to set page number when user scroll you can do like this

```
let pageNumber = 1;

$('.data-container').on('scroll', function (e) {
  const elem = $(e.currentTarget);
  
  if (elem[0].scrollHeight - elem.scrollTop() == elem.outerHeight()) {

    pageNumber++;
    
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: `/music-maker/page/${pageNumber}`,
      .......
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Hey man thanks for your time. I'm a little bit confused about the answer there. 1. Is my POST request to make the first search is alright? Should I keep it as it is? 2. You've provided the Ajax request to get data but how will I send the query to the backend as well? This is because my api request requires a query parameter as well.

Comment: see this get url `/music-maker/search/{your-query-here-or-keywords}` you can get the query there

Comment: Yes. I saw that but how to get it there? I tried that in the front end but it says undefined. And the query will come from the first search input from the user. Noob here mate. Please elaborate if you could.

Comment: So I will make the external api request in the server side code at the top? And could you please explain why you are sending query and page as json?

Comment: that only example how you send query from client to server and how server accept or process the request query.

Comment: okay mate. Please give me 5 mins. I'll implement this and get back to you.

Comment: yo, browser console shows this when I scroll at the bottom: ```GET http://localhost:3000/music-maker/search//2 404 (Not Found)```. Looks like user query is null or empty here in the error. I also did a console.log for the userInput value. It shows it is empty.

Comment: try `console.log($(".searchbar input").val());` make sure it return what you type in input form

Comment: I just did it again. One in getMusicMaker func and another in on scroll listener. Both ar empty.

Comment: Found the fix. I just have to keep the value in the input and not remove it in beforeSend

Comment: Mate, thank you so much. Learnt a lot from this. However, I had one question. What was wrong with my POST request before? Could this be done with the post request?

Comment: you're welcome. yes you can use POST but to make it not confused, use it both in new search and on scroll. your code not work because `userSearchInput` is not updating, you need to get again the input value when user scroll.

Comment: So not removing it from the input field will work? Or how do you suppose I'll update the input value when user scroll?